# How to check preg_match for complicated text?

Tags: php, preg-match

I've already seen some posts about it, but my text is a bit complicated,

And I can not get it to work.

Part of my page:

```
otherurl":"http:\/\/cdn1-test.peer5.net:80\/edge\/71-1.stream\/playlist.m3u8?uid=35577\u0026sil=3\u0026sip=WyIxODUuMTgueC54IiwiMjEwLj4LngiLCI54LngLjE1OC5giXQ%3D%3D\u0026sid=151078248\u0026misc=4OFxyLUs7UrIeWujPzuU%3D"}}
```

What I tried:

```
preg_match("/otherurl":"http:\/\/cdn1-test.peer5.net:80\/edge\/71-1.stream\/playlist.m3u8?uid=(.*)/", $data[$n], $output);
echo $output[1];
```

What I want to present:

Just the number after uid=*

Comment: What is the source of this string? It looks like it could be JSON, in which case after `json_decode()` it I would not try to preg_match, but instead some incantation of `parse_url()` & `parse_str()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, it's json but I wanted to know if there is a possibility to work only with a preg match and not a json decode

Comment: Is the `uid` always strictly a numeric string?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes

Comment: And does the `uid=` reliably appear as the first query parameter after `?`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string you receive is reliably formatted like your posted examples, where the `uid=` parameter is the first query parameter after `?` and is strictly a numeric string, you *can* use `preg_match()` to extract it by matching with `(\d+)` (match digits) because whatever follows in the next query parameter won't begin with a digit.

```
$str = 'otherurl":"http:\/\/cdn1-test.peer5.net:80\/edge\/71-1.stream\/playlist.m3u8?uid=35577\u0026sil=3\u0026sip=WyIxODUuMTgueC54IiwiMjEwLj4LngiLCI54LngLjE1OC5giXQ%3D%3D\u0026sid=151078248\u0026misc=4OFxyLUs7UrIeWujPzuU%3D"}}';

preg_match('/\?uid=(\d+)/', $str, $output);
echo $output[1];
// Prints "35577"
```

In practice I would avoid this though. The best way to handle this is to treat it as the JSON stream it is, in combination with PHP's built-in URL handling methods [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

That solution looks like:

```
// Note: I made this segment a valid JSON string...
$input_json = '{"otherurl":"http:\/\/cdn1-test.peer5.net:80\/edge\/71-1.stream\/playlist.m3u8?uid=35577\u0026sil=3\u0026sip=WyIxODUuMTgueC54IiwiMjEwLj4LngiLCI54LngLjE1OC5giXQ%3D%3D\u0026sid=151078248\u0026misc=4OFxyLUs7UrIeWujPzuU%3D"}';

$decoded = json_decode($input_json, TRUE);
// Parse the URL and extract its query string
// PHP_URL_QUERY instructs it to get only the query string
// but if you ever need other segments that can be removed
$query = parse_url($decoded['otherurl'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
// Parse out the query string into array $parsed_params
$params = parse_str($query, $parsed_params);
// Get your uid.
echo $parsed_params['uid'];
// Prints 35577
```

Comment: I tried, it works thanks a lot. and if (\d+) match numbers so what match letters? In case I want later

Comment: To match letters, I would use a `([a-z]+)` range and either the `/i` case-insensitive flag or `([A-Za-z]+)` upper & lower ranges. The `\d` shorthand can also be expressed as `([0-9]+)`